# Biblical Doctrine forbidding sex outside marriage

Tags: biblical-basis, bible-translation, biblical-theology

How do we get that “Sexual Immorality” equals “Sex outside of marriage?”

I cannot find Old Testament law stating it is forbidden. I can only find where sex outside of marriage, along with sexual immorality,gets termed as fornication.

I also hear the word Porneia translates as sex outside of marriage. My Strongs defines it as Deriving from harlotry (includ. Adultary and incest); fig. Idolatry

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  To understand how this site works, and what we look for in questions that show evidence of previous research and avoid opinion-based answers, please take our Tour: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: The real question that needs to be asked is 'Why would anyone _want_ to behave irresponsibly and copulate outside of a real, lasting, permanent union of parentage and family bonding and social normality ?' Society is coherent because of _families_. Otherwise, as is seen across the globe, society breaks down.

Comment: I have voted to close this question as it is a duplicate.

Comment: The drive is stronger for some Nigel. For some it is a burn that cannot be quenched. Don’t we all have our demons? No need to close it. After all, if the real question is “why would I want to” then you are taking it off course. The question was “is there biblical doctrine that forbids sex outside of marriage?”

Comment: @NigelJ I think asking "what's the basis for interpreting fornication as immorality in scripture" is distinct from "What is the biblical basis for prohibiting sex outside marriage". But when you look at the content of the other question, I see how it's probably too similar.

Answer (score 1):

> How do we get that “Sexual Immorality” equals “Sex outside of marriage?”

It is a very real possibility, biblically, that sexual union actually constitutes marriage.  You must read a long, long way into the Bible before you find anything that looks like a modern day, "I now pronounce you" type of scenario.  Biblically, ancient marriage included engagement, consummation, and public reception or witness.  Rather than a gathering officiated by a selected officiant there was an agreement made between the parties and, when the terms were met the two would go into the 'tent':

> And Isaac brought her into his mother Sarah's tent, and took Rebekah, and she became his wife;

In another place we are cautioned as believers not to resort to the use of harlots and this is couched in the same 'one flesh' terms as when marriage is spoken of:

> Know ye not that your bodies are the members of Christ? shall I then take the members of Christ, and make them the members of an harlot? God forbid. What? know ye not that he which is joined to an harlot is one body? for two, saith he, shall be one flesh. - 1 Corinthians 6:15-16

This passage in first Corinthians makes the phrase 'sex outside of marriage' into a nonsense phrase.  There is no sex that is outside of marriage, that's what makes immorality in this area so bad; every sexual union is a marital union.

Considered in this light it is easy to see why having multiple, casual sexual partners or same gender sexual partners or anything that is lumped into sexual immorality is just as egregious as what is normally considered as adultery.  God instituted marriage to be a one man and one woman, monogamous lifetime commitment and anything that falls outside of those parameters is an aberration of marriage.  Practicing anything else sexually is a distortion, not of sex so much, as of marriage.

But, considered in this same light it is not so easy to say that a man and a woman who have committed monogamously to one another before God without the trappings of a church officiant or legal documentation are living in sin.  Biblically speaking it is entirely likely that they are married in God's eyes from the moment of their first sexual union.

We tend to take sex way too lightly and the marriage ceremony way too seriously; especially since it is unlikely that the two should be considered separately.